# What's the best way to do wake-up word speech recognition in C#

Tags: c#, voice-recognition

I know how to make it so it'll trigger to different phrases, but I want one SpeechRecognitionEngine to listen for a wakeup word (example: trigger), then start another Engine to listen for everything until enough silence, and then save what I've said. If this isn't possible with SpeechRecognitionEngine, is there a way to do it in C# with an API of some sorts?

Comment: You can use `Azure Cognitive Services` https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/speech-services/

Comment: I was thinking at https://snips.ai. You may take a look on that but I am unsure what the pricing model for it is atm.

Answer (score -2):

Porcupine has support for C# it runs on Windows, Linux, and macOS at the moment. You can check the quick start on its [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Picovoice/porcupine#net-demos).